# Camera Hidden Behind Canvas in Unity Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

It's been a while since i opened Unity and I am having some trouble with one of my scenes. That scene has an overlay canvas which i can see in the editor.

I used to be able to double click on the camera and that would take me to my main scene contents(background and other sprites etc..). Now, when I double click, it does take me to the camera view but whatever is in there is now behind the canvas for some reason, and so I cannot see any of its elements.

Notice that the game displays just fine when the game runs, so the camera position is fine. It's just that I cannot edit whatever the camera shows, because it gets overlaid by my canvas on the editor. Any ideas ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a screenshot of what's actually going on?

Comment: added :) Thanks ! The Purple color is part of the Canvas HUD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistakenly rotated the camera in the *Scene View* and positioned it where everything is being blocked.

Things to try:

**1**.Select your 3D model from the *Hierarchy tab*, move the mouse into the *Scene View* and press *F*. This should focus the camera back to the 3D model.

**2**.If that did not work, hold the *Alt key*, position the mouse in the *Scene View*, hold down the left mouse button then try to mouse the mouse. This should rotate the camera to an angle that don't block the screen.

**3**.You can also use the mouse scroll-wheel to move the camera in/out of the UI in the *Scene View*. Do this if #1 and #2 did not work.

Comment: Hmm, couldn't make anything of those work. Btw, this is a 2D game. Not sure if the fact that I am coding on a mac changes requires different hotkeys than the ones mentioned. I did try changing the rotation of the camera from the editor, it was all 0s, which i think was always like that, didn't really make a difference.

Comment: If the camera was rotated wrong, shouldn't I be seeing the back side of the actual background ? The preview looks fine and also works fine when playing the game. It's only when i try to double click on the camera that i get the canvas on top of the camera instead.

Comment: My answer didn't say that the camera is rotated wrong. If the blocking  image is right in front of the camera and you rotate the camera, it should unblock. That's what I am trying to say. What is your Canvas Render mode set to? What is your camera projection mode? Can you check if you have multiple cameras with `Debug.Log(FindObjectsOfType<Camera>().Length);` then let me know.

Comment: Ah, ok I see. The camera render mode for the canvas hud is screen space - overlay. Camera projection mode is orthographic. Also using https://github.com/dfsp-spirit/way2close/blob/master/Way2Close/Assets/Scripts/ViewportHandler.cs for my camera. The debug statements shows that 1 camera is used only.

Comment: I didn't know you are using a plugin on the camera. Remove that `ViewportHandler` from the camera and try what's in my answer again

Comment: Unfortunately, not seeing a difference even with the script disabled. The weird thing is that this used to work just fine. However, I just noticed that if i disable the Canvas and then double click on the camera, the main scene actually shows fine on the editor. Maybe it has something to do with layers and precedence ? Both are on default right now. Moving them up and down in the hierarchy does not seem to be affecting it.

Comment: I guess I could have the Canvas disabled when editing the main scene, but I never had to do that before and it's really annoying :)

Comment: That's not normal. I think the only way to find out what's going on is to send me the scene if you don't mind. If you decide to do so, make a copy of the scenes then removed important files like graphics and audio. Just leave what's required to replicate the issue. That's the only thing I can tell you this moment

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) I literally have zero idea how this happened, but while going back and forth in some other scenes, I came back to that one and now things are working as they should. This leads to me to believe that there's either some kind of bug or i've made a mistake that I don't know I have and i fixed it without still knowing how :O

Comment: Hmm, what happened is that the camera was somehow moved to a transparent part of the canvas, that is why i can double click on it now. That's probably what happened originally. I may have moved the camera on the purple box location of the canvas and it was hidden behind it when double clicking to select it.

Comment: If that's the case, moving the camera either by the control keys or rotating should have fixed it, I suspect that the `ViewportHandler` script did something crazy to the camera. Glad you fixed it

Comment: Possible yes, could also be a difference in the mac hotkeys ? Thanks a lot for the help, appreciate that !

Comment: I use Windows on top of Mac and don't know Mac shortcut keys but that might be right.